# Automatically attach a file to a mail with mutt

Tags: email, mutt

I am searching for a way to automatically attach a file `~/.mutt/example.vcf` to any mail I compose with `mutt`.

I tried something like `send-hook 'attach-file ~/.mutt/fauve.vcf'` but it doesn't work.

Have you, please, any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in neomutt 20180716

```
macro compose y ":exec attach-file<enter>myfile.txt<enter>:exec send-message<enter>"
```

To explain:

- macro compose y -- override the y key in the compose menu to run a macro instead of just sending
- :exec attach-file -- opens the mutt prompt for a filename to attach
- myfile.txt -- enters the name of the file to attach and presses enter
- :exec send-message -- runs the send email command

Answer (score 0):

[edit]

Easiest solution consist in to just create a simple alias for mutt:

```
alias mutt="/usr/bin/mutt -a $HOME/.std.vcf"
```

so if you enter `mutt` `mutt -a $HOME/.std.vcf` will be executed. That's it!

Normally in order to compose a email with attachments `mime-construct` is used:

```
mime-construct --to "nerd@example" --subject 'hi there' \
--string "test" --file-attach /etc/motd
```

There are some solutions to automaticly add your *.vcf:

[vcf-to-mutt](http://vpim.rubyforge.org/vcf-to-mutt.txt)
[muttquery.py](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/QueryCommand)

However, it is unusual to use vcf on unices where a signature is more common.

Comment: I haven’t mime-construct installed so I can send mails with mutt.
Then, if what I want to do need the installation of mime-construct, I will install it.

Comment: Thank you for vcf-to-mutt and muttquery. I will try them.
Yes, I can use a link to my vcf but some email program sync automatically the addressbook when they found a vcf as an attachment. That’s why I prefer this way :)

Comment: Vcf-to-mutt is an interesting script. Thank you o/ but it doesn’t resolve my problem :)

Perhaps the solution are very complicated. Then as you tell me I will probably forget this idea and only quote the link to my vcard in a signature.

Thank you.

Comment: updated alias solution

Answer (score 0):

I dont know mutt, but I can tell you in mail or mailx I usually do `uuencode myAttachment.tar.gz attachmentName | mail -s "Here is that dolphin porn you requested" somedude@earthlink.cc.net.foo`

Comment: uuencode wasn’t installed in my system and was able to send mails with mutt.